# VBA Loop Overflow

Tags: vba, excel, overflow

I'm having the problem of loop overflow. Here is my code :

```
Private Sub DivideKPI()
    Dim FRow As Long
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim PRow As Long

    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Set CurrentSheet = Excel.ActiveSheet

    FRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    lrow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

    For PRow = lrow To 2 Step -1
        CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AO").Value = Round(((CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AK").Value) / (CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AM").Value)), 2)
    Next PRow
End Sub
```

If I put the 'PRow' manually instead of looping, the result can be produced. But I need to loop this coz there's so many data. How this can be done? I already use CLng but overflow also.
Thanks!

*Example Data

```
AK         AM
25.35      72
224.92     24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe `PRow` can be your problem. Try:

```
For PRow = lrow To 2 Step -1
        CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AO").Value2 = Round(((CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AK").Value2) / (CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AM").Value2)), 2)
    Next PRow
```

Comment: It's still same. Overflow TT.TT @Rory

Comment: What is the value of `PRow` at the time the error occurs and what is in the cells in columns AK and AM for that row?

Comment: From the beginning of looping. I try to capture it by doing 
     CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AP").Value = PRow 
but its already Overflow @Rory .

Comment: Can you put a workbook somewhere? I genuinely don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Ok, I already solve it. Need to filter out both AK and AM which contain no value. Thanks @Rory ! :)

Comment: For the record, that means your last comment made no sense. ;)